# How to show images from multiple directories in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to use a Wrapbootstrap template in my Rails application but it is unable to find my `images` as it is looking under welcome/build.  I believe it might be resolved by moving everything under `welcome/build/img` under `assets/images`? But how would I reference this in my `index.html.erb` file?

**All files under build folder are not being picked up:**

[image: Images not found]

**File structure from Chrome browser:**

[image: File system structure]

**Rake Routes:**

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
welcome_about GET  /welcome/about(.:format) welcome#about
welcome_index GET  /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
```

**Rails Version:**

Rails 4.2.8

**Ruby Version:**

2.5.1

**Index.html.erb file that is referencing the images not being found:**

```
<div class="product col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-product-id="1">
          <div class="inner-product">
            <span class="onsale new">New!</span>
            <div class="product-thumbnail">
              <img src="build/img/products/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="product-details text-center">
              <div class="product-btns">
                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add To Cart">
                  <a href="#!" class="li-icon add-to-cart"><i class="lil-shopping_cart"></i></a>
                </span>
                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to Favorites">
                  <a href="#!" class="li-icon"><i class="lil-favorite"></i></a>
                </span>
                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View">
                  <a href="product.html" class="li-icon view-details"><i class="lil-search"></i></a>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="product-title"><a href="#!">Unisex Cap</a></h3>
          <div class="star-rating">
            <span style="width:65%"></span>
          </div>
          <p class="product-price">
            <ins>
              <span class="amount">$99.99</span>
            </ins>
          </p>
        </div><!-- /.product -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, [**`How to Use the Asset Pipeline`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline). All images replace under `app/assets/images` and for view the image it will be

```
<%= image_tag "logo.svg", class: "img-responsive" %>
```

same as

```
<%= image_tag("logo.svg", class: "img-responsive") %>
```

**JavaScript:** Replace all the `js` files into `app/assets/javascripts` it will automatically mapping these files because of `//= require_tree .` in `application.js`

**Stylesheet:** Replace all the `css` files into `app/assets/stylesheets` it will automatically be mapping these files.

You must have to understand rails asset pipeline before starting this and go to provided URL and read carefully then apply.

**Update**

If your file under the deep directory like this `app/assets/build/img/products/product.jpg` then `image_tag` will like this for showing this image

```
<%= image_tag("build/img/products/product.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %>
#=> localhost:3000/assets/build/img/products/product.jpg
```

Generated HTML

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/build/img/products/product-005a83fc6c...xxx.jpg">
```

Comment: It will be `localhost:3000/assets/2.jpg` if has the image in `assets/images` folder @SaintClaire33

Comment: Thanks. It does not seem to work with my path.  There are multiple JPEGS that are supposed to be under assets/images/build/img/products.  But it is not finding it under the images directory using:  `<%= image_tag('/build/img/products/2.jpg', class: 'img-responsive product-img')`.

Comment: See this working on my hand `<%= image_tag("build/img/products/product.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %>` remove slash before `build`, I just tested out @SaintClaire33

Comment: Ah, I the forward slash. Thanks @fool-dev